# Incorrect Decimals & Max Total Supply ERC20 Token

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan, decimals

After deploying token contract on ethereum I am getting 0 decimals being shown on etherscan whilst other explorers displaying correctly.

[image: Image Showing 0 Decimals]

I presume because of this Max Total Supply displays as:-

```
3,200,111,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

When tokens are being sent, it shows the same. However in Metamask, or other explorer shows up as expected.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/presets/ERC20PresetMinterPauser.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";

/**
 * @title MyTestToken
 * @dev A capped ERC20 token contract with preset functionality 0f minter and pauser.
 */
contract MyTestToken is ERC20PresetMinterPauser, ERC20Capped {

    string public constant TOKEN_NAME = "MyTestToken";
    string public constant TOKEN_SYMBOL = "MyTestToken";
    uint256 public constant MAX_SUPPLY = 6300000000;
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 2100000000;

    event TokensMinted(address indexed _beneficiary, uint256 _amount, string _context);

    /**
     * @dev Constructor to initialize the token details and mint initial supply.
     * @param _beneficiary The address where initial supply will be minted.
     */

    constructor(address _beneficiary)
        ERC20PresetMinterPauser(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_SYMBOL)
        ERC20Capped(MAX_SUPPLY * 1 ether)
    {
        _mint(_beneficiary, INITIAL_SUPPLY *  1 ether);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual override(ERC20, ERC20PresetMinterPauser) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Creates amount of new tokens for account.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - the caller must have the `MINTER_ROLE`.
     *
     * @param _account The address where amount of tokens will be minted.
     * @param _amount The amount of tokens to be minted.
     * @param _purpose The purpose of minting the tokens.
     *
     */

    function mint(address _account, uint256 _amount, string memory _purpose) public {

        super.mint(_account,_amount);

        emit TokensMinted(_account, _amount, _purpose);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Creates amount new tokens for account.
     *
     * See {ERC20-_mint}.
     *
     */
    
    function _mint(
        address account,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual override(ERC20, ERC20Capped) {
        super._mint(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Can't share token address where this occurred.
Will share more information if can replicate. Deploying to testnet and other networks doesn't produce same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this fn in your code:-

```
function decimals() public view override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }
```

and also update the oz libraries with the newer one's.